# Why I can use rviz to show the depth points (Kinect Xbox 360)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All.
Today |I buy a xbox360 Kinect, install it on ubuntu 11.04 ros electric. Everything is fine.
But when I run
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
rosrun rviz rviz
I can see the rgb image.
But I can not see the depth image. I add one pointcloud2.
Set the Fixed Frame (top left of rviz window) to /camera_depth_optical_frame.

Add a PointCloud2 display, and set the topic to /camera/depth/points.
I can not see any information.
How to solve the problem.
I am sure the hardware s good,and it is normally from another computer.Only it is not worked for my laptop and desktop. Linux 11.04, ros electric.
I also try the kinet+mouse demo. it works.
Without depth information, I cannot try the roboearth package.
Thanks any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36752/why-i-can-use-rviz-to-show-the-depth-points-(kinect-xbox-360)/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer by my self.
Finally I find I just need set views as XYOrbit. And use mouse to select good view. Thus I can see the depth image.
It is really stupid but important.

---

Originally posted by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) with karma: 287 on 2012-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1